# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/5) on Chemistry has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Karsten Theis]

[image: Tyberius]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following users, who will be stepping down as moderators:

[image: Todd Minehardt]

[image: orthocresol]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4591166984028160).

Comment: Karsten and Tiberius, congratulations and welcome aboard! Safdar, I appreciate your decision to nominate yourself again. You have proven yourself worthy as a user and I'm sure you deserve the diamond too. Keep it up, don't be discouraged. Todd and ortho, I bow low for your assistance, integrity, and overall nice atmosphere. We've lost great mods, but gained even greater users. Last but not least, tons of compliments to JNat and CM team for helping with election and assuring the transition goes smoothly. As always, thank you all for playing and taking part in shaping Chemistry.SE!

Comment: Congratulations to you both, and I otherwise echo @andselisk's sentiments (except the ones that would be self-referential :))

Comment: Couldn't have summed it up better really. Congrats to the new mods, and although it can be quite a thankless job sometimes, I hope you find it rewarding in the same way I did. (Tyberius probably doesn't need to be told this. ;)) I wanted to thank people for their kind words, too, I appreciate it. As for Todd and I, it's time for freedom ;D

Comment: I don't want to sound like a parrot, so I'll be brief: thanks all around and congrats to the newlymods!

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators, and good luck to orthocresol for his future studies & Safdar should keep trying.